# How to check if $4 is registered in IRC?

Tags: irc, mirc

I am quite an expert when it comes to programming in the MSL language, however I am unfamiliar with raw commands and whatnot.

I am in development of a new script. In this script I would like to check if $4 in what a user says is a registered nick or not but I do not know how to do this.

Thank you very much for any help and/or advice in advanced.

Best Regards,
Tim

**Update:**

```
raw 307:*:{ set $+(%,%chan,-,%CheckNick) Registered }
on *:TEXT:*:#:{
    if ($1 == !regtest) {
        set %chan $remove($chan,$chr(35))

        set %CheckNick $4
        whois $4
    }
    if ($($+(%,%chan,-,%CheckNick),$4),5) != $null) {
        do this...
    }
    else {
        else message...
    }
}
```

I got this to work to check however my if statement to check if the variable has been set or not is being ignored...

**Edit:**

I tried using this:

```
checkNickReg $chan $2 $nick
```

...And echoing this:

```
  echo -a Target: $1
  echo -a Nick: $2
  echo -a Status: $3
  echo -a Chan: $3 - $chan
```

I'm trying to get a response to the channel such as; $nick $+ , $1 is not registered/registered/registered but not logged in.

What I've posted above is obviously wrong as it doesn't work, however I've tried a few methods and I'm actually not sure how the data is passed on with out the likes of tokenizing or setting variables...

**Reply**

[01:59:06] <~MrTIMarshall> !isReged mr-dynomite
[01:59:08] <&TornHQ> : mr-dynomite status is: NOTLOGGED
 
**EDIT:** mr-dynomite is not currently on, should this not = does not exist or does this check even when their not on, if so this is bloody brillant!!!
[02:00:04] <~MrTIMarshall> !isReged MrTIMarshall
[02:00:04] <&TornHQ> : MrTIMarshall status is: LOGGEDIN

$4 does not seem to work and what is the difference between 'exists, not logged in' and 'recognized, not logged in'?

Also, how does the data get passed on without setting variables or tokenizing?

(P.S. Thank you so much for the help you have dedicated so far!)

**Another Edit:**

I've been taking an in depth look today, am I correct in thinking if 0 or 1 the user is either not on-line or not registered (in the comments it says 0 = does not exists / not online, 1 = not logged in whereas 2 also says not logged in but recognized of which I'm unsure as what recognized means. Otherwise I'm very grateful for this script help and whatnot I'm just unclear on the numbers...

Comment: It's ircd specific.  Also, the L in MSL stands for language.

Comment: So, you want to look at IRCD Service daemons, and in particular NickServ commands.

Comment: Which networks do you want to target?

Comment: I only tend to use irc.torn.com port 6667

Comment: I updated my answer to support Torn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not specified any particular network I wrote an outline for some common networks around (that actually have user authentication systems). You should be able to add many other networks following the pattern.

Basically you execute `/checkNickReg <target> <nick> [optional extra data]` and when the server replays with the registration info (if applicable) use the `on isReged signal` event to handle the reply. Everything else is pretty much transparent.

**EDIT:** Looks like the specified network you are using (Torn) uses the standard anope services. So I updated the code to support that network.

```
; triggers when you get nick registration info back
; $1 = Target
; $2 = Nick
; $3 = Status, can be: LOGGEDIN, RECOGNIZED, NOTLOGGED
; $4- = Everything else passed
on *:signal:isReged:{
  echo -a Target: $1
  echo -a Nick: $2
  echo -a Status: $3
  echo -a Else: $4-
}

; reg lookup routines
alias checkNickReg {
  set %reg. $+ $network 1
  set %reg.target. $+ $network $1
  set %reg.nick. $+ $network $2
  set %reg.other. $+ $network $3-

  ; Freenode uses: NickServ ACC <nick>
  if ($network == Freenode) msg NickServ ACC $2
  ; Rizon/SwiftIRC/OFTC/Torn use: NickServ STATUS <nick>
  elseif ($istok(Rizon SwiftIRC OFTC Torn, $network, 32)) msg NickServ STATUS $2
}

; listen for replays
on *:notice:*:*:{
  if ($($+(%, reg., $network),2)) {
    ;
    var %target = $($+(%, reg.target., $network),2)
    var %nick = $($+(%, reg.nick., $network),2)
    var %other = $($+(%, reg.other., $network),2)
    ;
    unset %reg*. $+ $network

    if (($network == FreeNode) && ($2 == ACC)) $&
      || (($istok(Rizon SwiftIRC OFTC Torn, $network, 32)) && ($1 == STATUS)) {

      ; FreeNode:

      ; 0 = does not exist
      ; 1 = exists, not logged in
      ; 2 = recognized, not logged in
      ; 3 = logged in

      ; Rizon/SwiftIRC/OFTC/Torn:

      ; 0 = does not exists / not online
      ; 1 = not logged in
      ; 2 = recognized, not logged in
      ; 3 = logged in

      if ($3 < 2) var %status = NOTLOGGED
      elseif ($3 == 2) var %status = RECOGNIZED
      else var %status = LOGGEDIN
    }

    ;send status signal
    .signal isReged %target %nick %status %other 
  }
}
```

(Extra Note: It might be useful to add an extra check to make sure $nick is AuthServ/NickServ for security reasons.)

A simple usage example is:

```
; Just a basic example of how to call it.
on *:text:!isReged &:#:{
  checkNickReg $chan $2 $nick
}

on *:signal:isReged:{
  msg $1 $4: $2 status is: $3
}
```

Type `!isReged <nick>`

**Edit:** The data gets passed to the on isReged event via global variables. I set them in the `checkNickReg` alias and I clean them up in the `on notice` event. So you never see them because they get cleaned up. They are passed to the isReged signal event in $1-.

Comment: I've been looking through your provided code and I'll put it to test tomorrow as I'm heading off to bed any moment. It looks quite useful and I am grateful for what you've provided. I'll either select your answer the accepted one or leave another reply once I awake.

Comment: Looks like Torn uses standard anope services, so I just added it to the list with the other networks. It should work just fine. Of course if you only want to use that network, you can trim that script down a bit.

Comment: This is brilliant, I have literally only loaded it to give it a little test and I can see a lot of potential to use this script for more than the little one I'm currently working on. - I'm just having a minor problem to echo the channel the command was entered in...

Comment: That's what the target I have set for. If it's an on text in a channel for example, and you wanted to check if $nick is registered, you'd use ``checkNickReg $chan $nick``. When you get the info back in the ``on isReged signal``, ``$1`` will be $chan, ``$2`` will be $nick, and ``$3`` will be the status.

Comment: @TimMarshall See the example usage in my answer.

Comment: I don't think you updated your code to what my last version is. (The actual checkNickReg and on notice code)

Comment: @TimMarshall Currently I have it return ``NOTLOGGED`` if the user is not logged in as well as if the user doesn't exist or not online. The reason being is on some networks (Torn included) 0 can mean either "they are not online" or "the user doesn't exist". There is no way to tell the difference. So I just return ``NOTLOGGED`` since it's the only sane thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

On most IRCDs, it's only exposed in the WHOIS response for a user, if at all. Running a WHOIS every time a user says something is inadvisable, especially because server admins may receive a notification every time it happens.

Comment: No, this is just for a command for my staff, the bot would only listen on a certain on TEXT command and check if the $4 is a registered nick or not...